# Error message:ORA-01403: no data found

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new to coding in Oracle SQL Developer, and now i've gotten the task to list all projects in the category I insert. I keep getting either "Error message:ORA-01403: no data found" or the error message where they say I have too many rows. Could someone please look at my code?

```
procedure LIST_PROJECTS_PP ( --Elaine
p_catName           IN VARCHAR2      -- required
)

IS 
  ex_ERROR             EXCEPTION;
  ex_errorMsg_txt      VARCHAR(100);
  v_catName_txt        GG_Projcat.Category_Name%type;
  v_projstatus_txt     GG_Project.Project_Status%type;
  v_projtitle_txt      GG_Project.Project_Title%type;
  v_projorg_txt        GG_Project.Org_ID%type;
  v_projcount_txt      GG_Project.Country_ISO3166%type;
  v_projgoal_txt       GG_Project.Project_Goal%type;
  v_projID_txt         GG_Project.Project_ID%type;

BEGIN
  SELECT GG_PROJECT.Project_Title, GG_PROJECT.Project_ID, GG_PROJCAT.Category_Name, GG_PROJECT.Project_Status INTO v_projtitle_txt, v_projID_txt, v_catname_txt, v_projstatus_txt
  FROM GG_PROJECT, GG_PROJCAT
  WHERE GG_PROJECT.PROJECT_ID = GG_PROJCAT.PROJECT_ID
  AND p_catname = category_name
  AND GG_PROJECT.PROJECT_STATUS = 'active';
  COMMIT;
  DBMS_output.put_line('Project Title: '|| v_projtitle_txt);

  IF v_catname_txt IS NULL THEN
    ex_errorMsg_txt := 'Category does not exist';
    RAISE ex_ERROR;
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN ex_ERROR THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (ex_errorMsg_txt);
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('An error occured.') ;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Error code:  ' || SQLCODE) ;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Error message:' || SQLERRM) ;
END LIST_PROJECTS_PP;
```

Answer (score 1):

To receive multiple rows in a procedure you must use a cursor:

```
FOR rec in (SELECT GG_PROJECT.Project_Title, GG_PROJECT.Project_ID, GG_PROJCAT.Category_Name, GG_PROJECT.Project_Status INTO v_projtitle_txt, v_projID_txt, v_catname_txt, v_projstatus_txt
  FROM GG_PROJECT, GG_PROJCAT
  WHERE GG_PROJECT.PROJECT_ID = GG_PROJCAT.PROJECT_ID
 AND p_catname = category_name
 AND GG_PROJECT.PROJECT_STATUS = 'active') LOOP
   DBMS_output.put_line('Project Title: '|| rec.Project_Title);
end loop;
```